# C++ lambda followed by () vs. lambda without ()

Tags: c++, lambda

What is the difference between these two blocks of code?

```
struct HighResClock
{
    typedef long long                               rep;
    typedef std::nano                               period;
    typedef std::chrono::duration<rep, period>      duration;
    typedef std::chrono::time_point<HighResClock>   time_point;
    static const bool is_steady = true;

    static time_point now();
};


namespace
{
    auto g_Frequency = []() -> long long
    {
        std::cout<<"HERE";
        LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
        return frequency.QuadPart;
    }();
}

HighResClock::time_point HighResClock::now()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER count;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&count);
    return time_point(duration(count.QuadPart * static_cast<rep>(period::den) / g_Frequency));
}

int main()
{
    HighResClock c;
    c.now();
    c.now();
    c.now();
}
```

and

```
struct HighResClock
{
    typedef long long                               rep;
    typedef std::nano                               period;
    typedef std::chrono::duration<rep, period>      duration;
    typedef std::chrono::time_point<HighResClock>   time_point;
    static const bool is_steady = true;

    static time_point now();
};


namespace
{
    auto g_Frequency = []() -> long long
    {
        std::cout<<"HERE";
        LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
        return frequency.QuadPart;
    };
}

HighResClock::time_point HighResClock::now()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER count;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&count);
    return time_point(duration(count.QuadPart * static_cast<rep>(period::den) / g_Frequency()));
}

int main()
{
    HighResClock c;
    c.now();
    c.now();
    c.now();
}
```

In case you did not notice, the difference is the bracket below:

```
auto g_Frequency = []() -> long long
{
    LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
    return frequency.QuadPart;
}(); //this bracket here appears in one and not the other..
```

I ask because the one with the bracket only prints "Here" once, whereas the other (without the bracket) prints it 3 times. What does the bracket mean and what does it do? Is there a name for this syntax with the bracket?

Comment: One has HERE the other Here :)

Comment: Ahahaha.. +1 for humor. I meant the bracket though. It's my first time seeing a bracket after a lambda and I can't find any other examples online.

Comment: I wish I knew what the difference is, I never saw "auto", so I am not sure what it does, nor what `= [] ()` is .. sorry, usually `()` at the end mean execute, rather than assign values

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Writing `()` immediately after the lambda definition `[]{}();` will call the lambda, so the result is of type of the return type of the lambda.

If you omit the `()` suffix, a lambda type (unspecified) will be returned, which is basically a callable functor.

```
auto result = []{ return 42; }(); // auto is integer, result has 42 in it  
auto result1 = []{ return 42; }; // auto is some unspecified lambda type  
auto result2 = result1(); // auto is integer, result2 is storing 42` 
......................^^ - this is the bracket you can also put directly after the definition of the lambda
```

Comment: Thank You! For the life of me, I could not see that. So with the brackets g_Frequency is a variable of return type and without the brackets g_Frequency is a lambda? `EDIT:` I'll accept this as soon as it lets me

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames yeah, I included an example

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are *two* differences between the code segments:

1. One code segment has the parenthesis after the lambda immediately executing it and yielding a `long` and no parenthesis after the use of `g_Frequency`, merely reading its value.
2. The other code segment doesn't have the parenthesis after the lambda, i.e., `g_Frequency` becomes a function object and there are parenthesis after the use of `g_frequency` making it a call to a function.